# Drop Folder in Chrome (55)

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I am trying to load a folder via drag & drop from the desktop.

The attached code reports the following error when type.isDirectory.

> error ** A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded 
>   the URL length limitations for Data URLs.

There is a bit more detail provided by the error in the snippet.

I have tried e.dataTransfer.files, but there is no createReader() available on the .files object.

```js
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
    dropzone.ondragover = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    dropzone.ondrop = function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault();
       var items, 
           type;
          items = e.dataTransfer.items;
          //items = e.dataTransfer.files;
          for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
            type = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if ( type.isDirectory ) { 
              type.createReader()
                    .readEntries(
                        res => console.log('result',result), 
                        e   => console.log('error **',e)
                     )}               
            }
        }
```

```css
div#dropzone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone"></div>
```